# How can we make the tag 'ingredient-selection' less confusing?

Tags: discussion, tags

A lot of new users are confused about the tag 'ingredient-selection'. It would seem to apply to things like "Why were apples used in this recipe" or "Should I substitute peaches or pears in this recipe?", but it does not. Instead it to things like "How can I tell an apple is ripe?" Both types of questions have to do with selecting ingredients; is there something we can rename the tag to to make it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

The [tag wiki](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/ingredient-selection/info) would seem to make it clear, and we went out of our way to create that new tag in order to quarantine the original (horrible and now-abolished) "ingredients" tag.

I am personally on record several times as saying that if users are consistently using the wrong tag, then it is probably a problem with the tag, not the users. So I'm usually on the lookout for this type of tag problem, and well-aware of the frustrating misuse of this particular tag. But I'm just not sure how much clearer we can make it without resorting to even worse tags like *[shopping]*.

To *select* means to *"carefully choose as being the best or most suitable"*. That doesn't connote (to me) questions about substitutions, or recipe modification, or about ingredients in general.

I think the existing tag is the best option among many lukewarm alternatives, but of course, I'm open to suggestions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of another possibility: [ingredient-quality](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ingredient-quality).

We already have [food-identification](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food-identification) which covers the non-"quality" side of selection.

Would this be less easily abused, or possibly worse?